# Audio crackling and popping with different audio devices (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, audio

I've been having this weird audio problem somewhat related to CPU/GPU load with every audio device I've tried.
Under moderate load, audio starts to crackle and pop, no matter what audio device I'm using. I've tried USB audio (Logitech G930) and on-board Realtek audio drivers, using them with Microsoft basic drivers or manufacturer supplied drivers. I have reinstalled Windows several times. I've also tried with Windows 7 (my current OS is Windows 10), and IIRC the problem persisted there.

Weird thing is, that with Steam In-Home streaming to another computer, **audio works just fine** (on the client computer the audio is crystal clear, but on the sending computer the audio is cracking and popping). I've also tried the same by streaming audio to another computer using Voicemeeter/VBAN, but the problem persists there. So I'm suspecting that Windows' audio handling does something weird (buffer underruns or something) and I've been trying to give audio processes/services higher priority, but without success.

I've also updated the UEFI/BIOS.

My computers specs also shouldn't be a problem:

- Intel i5-6600K
- NVidia GTX 1070 (also tried with 550 Ti and 680)
- 8 GB of RAM (Kingston HyperX Fury Black 2 x 4 GB (DDR4, 2666 MHz, CL15))
- Asus Z170-A (motherboard, with Realtek on-board audio)
- Logitech G930 (USB wireless audio)

Some people have found success by disabling possible audio enhancements or tweaking power settings, but I've tried those too. I have also disabled every audio device and tried them one by one, with Windows default basic drivers. Problem persists.

What could I possibly do next?

Comment: Try swapping your default audio from 48kHz to 44.1kHz in your sound manager.

Comment: Check the screws that hold the motherboard to the case. Make sure they are tight  Excessive crackling like this this is often a grounding issue and your electronics/case may not be properly grounded. Also, if you are using an external audio front panel, I would recommend using the built in audio on the back of the computer instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tried with 44.1kHz with different audio devices, problem persists.

Comment: @Narzard I've tried with both front and back connectors AND with USB audio device (which shouldn't be affected by possible grounding issues), problem persists.

Comment: btw, crackling is not a grounding issue, it's a decoding/timing issue

Comment: @Tetsujin And as I said, with audio/video streaming to another computer using Steam audio works. So I guess the issue is somehow related to the late stages of Windows audio output to devices after receiving it from different sources. I don't know where Steam grabs its audio, so that's a mystery.

Comment: I'm not that au fait with Win audio, I'm afraid, i'm Mac... & if it doesn't work properly on Mac, then all you can do is hope there are newer drivers

Comment: use this script to capture a trace while you have the audio issues: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2017/01/09/collecting-audio-logs-the-old-fashioned-way/ . Zip the generated ETL file and share it (onedrive share link). I'll analyze why you see audio issues.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I played a game to have the audio crackle. Here's the zip that the script created https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ngg3hnzcpntcfmb/RAILGUN_20170124-091440.zip

Comment: I posted what I saw from the trace.

Comment: Audio streaming (steam etc) uses buffers and buffers mitigate this sort of problem. You might try the opposite: raise the sample rate to 96k (or whatever is native for the audio chipset). If the native rate is different than the selected rate, then there is upsampling or downsampling. This means latency.

Answer (score 0):

keep default settings (default buffer size) and select your best audio device as output A1 (giving the main stream) : First try ASIO device or WDM/KS... use MME device at the end if nothing works. Check you have no audio conflict (audio device not used twice by several apps).

Think about installing last version (currently presented on vb-audio facebook/g+) Voicemeeter 2017 Version 2.0.3.2 / 1.0.5.2 (REBOOT after de-installation, REBOOT after installation)...

If the problem remains, you may contact vb-audio with a screenshot of your Voicemeeter and its system settings dialog box.

Comment: I think you possibly misread the question. I'm not having specifically Voicemeeter problems, but other audio problem that didn't solve itself when trying with Voicemeeter.

Comment: ok, right, your problem seems to be more located on system or driver level (maybe motherboard bus or bad video/network driver can disturb windows timing) but keeping default settings on Voicemeeter and select your best audio device as output A1 can help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You get [DPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Procedure_Call) issues with come from the Microsoft USB 3.0 driver `USBXHCI.SYS`:

```
Total = 11776 for module USBXHCI.SYS
Elapsed Time, >      256 usecs AND <=      512 usecs,     12, or   0.10%
Elapsed Time, >      512 usecs AND <=     1024 usecs,      1, or   0.01%
Elapsed Time, >     1024 usecs AND <=     2048 usecs,      0, or   0.00%
Elapsed Time, >     2048 usecs AND <=     4096 usecs,      7, or   0.06%
Elapsed Time, >     4096 usecs AND <=     8192 usecs,      1, or   0.01%
Total,                                                 11776
```

Everything over 1024µs is bad and you have 8 spikes where it takes longer and this causes the audio drops. Connect your USB devices that don't require fast data transfer (mouse, keyboard) to USB 2.0 ports and not USB 3.0 ones.

Also the `NDIS.sys` causes some drops:

```
Total = 3960 for module ndis.sys
Elapsed Time, >     1024 usecs AND <=     2048 usecs,      3, or   0.08%
Elapsed Time, >     2048 usecs AND <=     4096 usecs,     17, or   0.43%
Total,                                                  3960
```

So update the network card drivers and all network related drivers.

If the sound/audio is fine over Displayport or HDMI on an external Monitor/TV, the cheap Realtek audio chip is causing the issue.

Buy a soundcard with a better audio chip like the [ASUS Strix Soar](http://www.asus.com/Sound-Cards/STRIX-SOAR/specifications/)

[image]

and connect your headphones to this sound card and disable the Realtek chip in BIOS.

Comment: Few spikes sounds a lot less than it feels. The audio very bad under some load. I switched every USB device to USB 2.0 ports, disabled networking entirely, but the audio is still crackling under load. I took another trace without networking: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hjhajrinm4dadd3/RAILGUN_20170125-063537.zip

Comment: the new trace shows less spikes, only 2 (1 in USB3 driver and 1 in storport.sys - storage related driver) that reach 1024µs. But I still see that the logitech driver **LGSHidFilt.sys** is called by the usb3 driver. Was the sound still so bad when you captured the new trace?

Comment: Yes, the sound was still as bad as before. My wireless headset is by Logitech, so that's the driver. The headset was plugged into USB 2.0 port, so that's weird that USB3 driver would try to use it.

Comment: ok, in this case the issues are not caused by DPCs. connect a Monitor/TV via HDMI so that the audio of the GPU is used. look if the sound from the TV is also bad or not.

Comment: Huh, audio through DisplayPort -> Display -> Headphone out -> Wired headphones is just fine with no crackling. Weird, I was pretty sure that I did try audio through GPU before. Maybe the display has audio buffer? Still, this is a workaround at best. I'd still like to use my wireless headphones.

Comment: ok, so the cheap audio chip from realtek causes the issues. Buy a PCI-e based sound card with a better chip like this one: http://www.asus.com/Sound-Cards/STRIX-SOAR/ if you buy such a high end PC, you should not try to save money on the sound

Comment: But can the Realtek chip cause these issues also with the wireless headset? Because it's happening. I'd understand if I was using the Realtek chip for my audio output and it had problems, but the problem occurs also with the USB wireless headset.

Comment: the Realtek chips are cheap products. if you want better quality use a better sound card

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but still I'm baffled how the chip could cause audio issues even when **I'm not using it**. I've disabled it in Device Manager and Logitech has its own audio drivers.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe the windows audio stack enums all audio chips each time and this causes issues.

Comment: I just disabled the Realtek chip from BIOS/UEFI and the problem still persists. I'm just not so sure that a new sound card would solve this.

Comment: you sad the logitech also has a chip. maybe this is also such a cheap sound chip. does the headphone has a Cinch/RCA connector?

Comment: The headset uses a USB receiver that has never had any sort of problem before this computer. And it's wireless only. Also the audio problems are the same no matter which device I use - Realtek on-board or Logitech wireless.

Comment: I have no real idea. use the Displayport workaround to get good sound.